# Displaying unique records in combo-box in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am displaying almost 9000 records by four type (A,B,C & D) in which I am displaying records using combo-box.

Each record is classified by "ctype" ( A or B or C or D) so I am putting this in combo so that If I select type A then all records of type A will be display..

Code that I am following :

Code link : http://jsfiddle.net/sunilspalkar/hdmNx/1/

In above code all records displaying but its not showing unique records of dam . I am facing same problem..

What I tried :

1.I am using query layer &  I can not use "distinct"  because of "geom" column .
2.I searched the API reference also for "unique elements for combo-box" but I did not found suitable material.
3. I found this [link](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/10/07/using-javascript-to-populate-a-combobox-with-unique-values/) In this link values are hard coded and I have dynamic values.
4. If I use "STATE" column instead of "ctype" then it works fine.. the "ctype" column has string type and all records are well formatted..

Software's : Sql Server 2008 r2 (for query layer) , ArcGIS Server/Desktop 10.1 , Java script API ver. 3.0/3.1

Comment: Also checked the "query task API reference" for version 3.0/3.1

Comment: Hello All..this may be irrelevant but how many query layers can I use in ArcMap ? At present I am using two but I am unable to publish two query layers in ArcGIS Server 10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want the list to show a list of unique dam values? You need to filter your array to get them. Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dave_wilton/hdmNx/6/

It assumes you are using name to filter on:

```
    function cleanFilterValues(values) {
      var unique = {};
      //get rid of duplicates
      return dojo.filter(values, function(value) {
             if (!unique[value.name]) {
             unique[value.name] = true;
             return true;
       }
     return false;
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..Yes I want to display  unique dam values..I will test and let you know...thanks : )

Comment: I've moved your code in to the JS file. Don't put your code in the markup http://odoe.net/blog/?p=212

Comment: Sorry link to updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dave_wilton/hdmNx/10/

Comment: @David..Thanks for your fast reply..Good news is that is working perfect for 1000 records.. for next 8000 records its not working..may be due to performance issue ESRI restricts to only 1000 records(combo-box sorting only 1000 records) ..so if anybody know this limitation then please let us know.. thanks once again David W. : )

Comment: ArcGIS server is limited to returning 1000 records (although it can be changed with caution). You should probably ask this as a separate question but I would suggest looking at using the new statistics class which if used with return geometry = false will return more than 1000. It will also return unique values and get rid of the need for the above code. Requires 10.1 http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm

Comment: & all ...Yes we can change the record numbers for that you have to changes in map service..more details please check this on esri forum here(http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/72913-Combo-box-limitation-%281000-records%29-for-AGIS-JSAPI-ver.-3.0-%28-amp-probably-3.2-also%29)

Comment: @Sunil Yes you can change it, but I wouldn't recommend it for what you are doing. Check out the statistics, it will provide much better performance. Returning 9000 geometries = slow. use statistics to get the unique values and in the onChange event use query task to get your geometry